# How do you unzip a file that is a base64 string, then create that file on your PC ? Base64 was retrieved from Selenium API

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am following the steps here:

[File Download on server, then retrieve Base64 from API via Selenium API](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/configuration/cli_options/#enabling-managed-downloads-by-the-node)

The above URL shows (in Java, not C#) how to get the zipped Base64 representation of a txt file from a server, via API, then using that zipped Base64 file representation, save to a txt file on your local.

The original file (on the server) is located at the below URL:

[File](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/web/downloads/download.html)

[image]

It transfers the zipped Base64 representation of this file through API. I do not know how to properly unzip this Base64 then save to txt file. The URL above only shows a Java example.

The Base64 response is as follows:

> UEsDBBQACAgIACxiTVcAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKAAAAZmlsZV8xLnR4dPNIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVHkAgBQSwcIhJ7otBAAAAAOAAAAUEsBAhQAFAAICAgALGJNV4Se6LQQAAAADgAAAAoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGZpbGVfMS50eHRQSwUGAAAAAAEAAQA4AAAASAAAAAAA

The C# code that I have added properly saves a zip file from the BAse64 string.

```
var path = @"c:\seleniumdownloads\transferredandunzippedfile.zip";
byte[] zipBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    fs.Write(zipBytes, 0, zipBytes.Length);
}
```

I can then manually unzip it in Windows Explorer to retrieve the `.txt` file. But I need to know how to unzip it within code. I don't want to instead 'save' a zip file on my PC.

Even though the next block of code is irrelevant to my questions, I will include it anyway. Below is the C# code that I have added to get the base64 string:

```
DownloadBtn.Click();

dynamic json = APIUtils.ExecuteAPIGet(SeleniumGridHubUri + "/session/MySessionID/se/files");

string fileToDownload = json.value.names[0];

object bodyOfAPI = new { name = fileToDownload };

dynamic json2 = APIUtils.ExecuteAPIPost(SeleniumGridHubUri, bodyOfAPI);

string base64String= json2.value.contents;
```

Comment: Post the Selenium code that downloads the file. Selenium saves the file locally, it doesn't convert it to BASE64. Specifically, Selenium drives the *browser*, which downloads the file locally. Once that completes, you can specify the final destination of that file. The *browser* doesn't retrieve nor convert anything to BASE64. I use this to download data files from a web site that doesn't offer a proper API

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos To download the file, you just use the click command in Selenium IWebElement.Click(). Yes it does download that file (But if you are executing the test on a Selenium Grid through servers, not your local, it does NOT download the file locally to your local, instead it downloads the file on the server (to the /tmp directory), but then you execute the API that is explained within the Selenium URL that I provided. That API is what converts to Base64 for you to use locally

Comment: That link isn't about downloading with Selenium, it's about retrieving files *as JSON* from a remote Grid node using its API. Post your actual code. There's too much confusion right now. What you show looks like  a ZIP file that was saved with a `.txt` extension, not the uncompressed contents. You didn't post any code that actually unzips `zipBytes`

Comment: When I use an online BASE64 decoder the result is different from the screenshot. ZIP files start with `PK`. The online decoder does show `PK` at the start but the screenshot doesn't

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In regards to the confusion of my post, I have now updated/clarified my post to represent the actual scenario (Not transferring a file from server to local, but instead retrieving Base64 representation of file from server to local). In regards to posting my code unzipping the contents, that is what I am asking I think. I thought my code above was uncompressing, but it is not as you have stated. So that is the code I need I would imagine

Comment: You haven't clarified anything. Your screenshot shows that you saved a ZIP file with a `.txt` extension instead of `.zip`, then tried to open the ZIP file as if it was text. At the very least change the extension to ZIP and try to unzip the file.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Which online decoder did you use?

Comment: Why don't you fix the extension instead, and try to unzip the file using any tool you like? On Windows you can double click on a ZIP file to see its contents

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My end-result/goal is to uncompress and/or save the Base64 as a text file, WITHIN the code. Not manually after saving it as a ZIP file

Comment: Change the extension. Prove to yourself it's a ZIP file. Then google `C# ZIP`. You'll find there's a ZipArchive class in .NET

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If you look at the Selenium URL I provided, the end-result is uncompressing WITHIN code, resulting in an exact match of file contents from the original file on server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok I will do that

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok yes when I saved as a ZIP file, then I manually unzipped, the result was that the contents of the text file match the server. And that was my original question, but maybe got confused, sorry about that. But the question still remains, how to unzip WITHIN code. I dont want to save the base64 string as a zip file at all.

Comment: KenWhite I apologize for all of the confusion. But I was not comprehending some things that @PanagiotisKanavos was saying. I should have read more carefully. Can you both review my updated post and let me know if that wording is better than the original?

Comment: Did you google for `ZipArchive`? The [ZipArchive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=net-7.0) class can read a ZIP file, enumerate its contents and open them. You can wrap `zipBytes` into a `MemoryStream` and pass that to ZipArchive's constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FromBase64String` gives you the contents of the ZIP archive. You need to unzip this to get to the files in the archive. .NET has the [ZipArchive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=net-7.0) class for reading and writing ZIP files.

The class's constructor accepts a Stream to the data. You can wrap `zipBytes` in a MemoryStream to allow ZipArchive to work with it.

Once you open the archive you can iterate over its [Entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.entries?view=net-7.0), and access each entry's contents as a stream with [ZipArchiveEntry.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.open?view=net-7.0)
:

```
using var zipStream=new MemoryStream(zipBytes);
using var archive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
{
    using var entryStream=entry.Open();
    //Do something with the data,eg copy it to disk
    using targetStream=File.Create(entry.Name);
    entryStream.CopyTo(targetStream);
}
```